# Calculation of Chern number of $U(N)$ principal bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I am considering $U(N)$ principal bundle on a two-dimensional sphere $S^2$. 
(Below the fiber is $N\times N$ unitary matrices for simplicity, and any generalization to general representations will be appreciated.)

The bundle is defined by the transition function $t(\theta)\in U(N)$ along the equator $S^1$ parametrized by $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. I am trying to calculate the first Chern number of this bundle and wondering whether it is generally possible to do a (globally defined, of course) gauge transformation to get an equivalent principal bundle defined by $\tilde{t}(\theta)$ so that
\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde{t}(\theta)\in \left[U(1)\right]^N, 
\end{eqnarray}
where $\left[U(1)\right]^N$ is the Cartan subgroup of $U(N)$, namely diagonal matrices.

Does such gauge transformation exist generally? If so, the first Chern number can be always calculated by abelian subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. And you can do better.

Observe that the clutching function  is determined by its homotopy class $t\in \pi_1(U(N))$. Note that there is a homeomorphism $U(N)\cong U(1)\times SU(N)$. Since $SU(N)$ is simply connected we get $\pi_1(U(N))\cong \pi_1(U(1))$, so we can choose $t$ to factor through the inclusion $U(1)\hookrightarrow U(N)$ up to homotopy as $t:S^1\xrightarrow{\bar t}U(1)\hookrightarrow U(N)$, and $U(1)$ certainly lies inside the diagonal subgroup $U(1)^N$.

So yes, the first Chern class of any bundle over $S^2$ (in fact over any 2- or 3-dimensional CW complex) is determined by the abelian subgroup $U(1)$. For higher dimensional spaces this will not always be true.

Note that this is not the same as the diagonal $U(1)$-subgroup, consisting of matrices $\lambda\cdot I_n$ with $\lambda \in S^1$. The inclusion of this subgroup induces multiplication by $N$ on $\pi_1$, since it factors as $\pi_1(U(1))\xrightarrow{\Delta}\pi_1(U(1)^N)\hookrightarrow \pi_1(U(N))$ where the first map is induced by the diagonal. This means that $t$ is deformable to a map in the image of this incusion if and only if it has degree $0\mod N$.

Comment: Many thanks, and although I have not checked completely, I totally agree with you since we can indeed construct a single U(1) (mixing diagonal u(1) and the last u(1) in Cartan of su(N)) to compute the minimal nonzero 1st Chern number.

Comment: In addition, can we generalize this argument towards U(1)*SU(N)*SU(k) or more as well? (where u(1) is the diagonal u(1)) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your notation means in your second comment. Could you clarify please?

Comment: My apology. I meant the fiber is generalized to the direct product of $U(1)=exp(i\phi)$, $SU(N)$ (N by N special unitary matrix) and $SU(k)$  (k by k special unitary matrix).

Comment: Yes. We have $\pi_1(U(1)\times SU(N)\times SU(k))=\pi_1(U(1))$, with the isomorphism induced by the inclusion and projection of $U(1)$ into the product. The exact same reasoning lets you conclude that the clutching function only depends on what it does inside $U(1)$ (up to homotopy). Note however that $U(N)$ is not a direct product. It is only *homeomorphic* to $U(1)\times SU(N)$, although this is enough to let you conclude the result.

Comment: Sorry for one more question: can we do the same or similar thing such as diagonalization of transition function on the equator $S^1$ when the fiber is the Kronecker product of $N$ by $N$ unitary matrices $U(N)$ and $k$ by $k$ unitary matrices $U(k)$, namely the principal bundle $U(N)\otimes U(k)\rightarrow S^2$ with $\otimes$ matrix Kronecker product? (I have tried many ways analogously to your method but failed eventually.) Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the direcet product $U(N)\times U(k)$? For $N,k\geq 1$ these groups are nonabelian, so their Kronecker product is not defined.

Comment: I define such product as the matrix Kronecker product. If I remember correctly, Kronecker product can be done for any two matrices. Or equivalently, you can see such Kronecker product space as a quotient as $[U(N)\times U(k)]/U(1)$ where $U(1)$ is elements in $\{(a,a^{-1})|a\in U(1)\}$.

Comment: the Kronecker product is defined for matrices, but in the context of algebras, and does not extend to a group homomorphism. It's not equivalent to the second definition you give, which is, however, well defined when you take $U(1)$ as the diagonal central subgoup $\lambda\cdot I_N$. This a  more difficult problem. Writing $G=(U(N)\times U(k))/\Delta(U(1))$ we have $\pi_1G=<(x,y)|Nx=kY>$ so you can lift a class in $\pi_1G$ to $U(N)\times U(k)$, further reduce to one of three cases i) $U(1)\times 0$, ii) $0\times U(1)$, iii) $U(1)\times U(1)$ and then look at the subgroup this generates in $G$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the homeomorphism between spaces rather than group homomorphism. Such lifting indeed works since we have a long exact sequence to prove that the quotient-induced mapping from $\pi_1(U(N)\times U(k))$ to $\pi_1(U(N)\times U(k)/U(1))$ is surjective. Then we can see that the homotopy group is the third case you mentioned: $U(1)\times U(1)$.